# Tensorflow, I got a Shape mismatch in execution time

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Good Afternoon Everyone,

I am currently having some trouble with tensorflow, since for some reason I get a Shape error after about 3 and a half hours running. The files are loaded using the tensorflow pipeline, and creating two reinitializable datasets for training and test. I know the data has the correct shape because I do a hardcoded reshape to the expected shape and I've never got an error there. The problem is, when running the network at some point there is a sample that do not have the correct amount of number in the flatten operation. And the program crashes, but there is no other explanation other than the number of elements in the tensor is not divisible by 10 (my batch size). Which honestly makes no sense to me since the data has gone exactly through the same pipeline as the other batches that run with no problem.

I can provide code if needed, but I think is more a failure to understand some concept from the framework.

Thanks in advance for all the help.

EDIT: Please, find the code here, a bit of nomemclature t corresponds to a layer that has time data (X), f corresponds to a layer that has frequency data (FREQ), q corresponds to a layer that contains cepstral data (QUEF) and tf corresponds to layers that contain 2-D data, spectrograms of X (SPECG), Y is the label. All data are tf.float32 except for the labels which are tf.int64

EDIT 2: The operation that gives problems is the flatten on qsubnet_out

EDIT 3: Probably the most important, it seems than some of the layers converge to NaNs
Training loop:

```
for i in range(FLAGS.max_steps):
    start = time.time()
    sess.run([train],feed_dict={handle:train_handle})
    if i%10 == False:
        summary_op,entropy,acc,expected,output = sess.run([merged,loss,accuracy,Y,tf.argmax(logit,1)],feed_dict={handle:train_handle})
        summary_op,_,_ = sess.run([merged,loss,accuracy],feed_dict={handle:test_handle})
```

Training operations:

```
W = { 'tc1': [64,3], 'tc2':[128,3], 'tc3':[256,5], 'tc4': [128, 2],
              'fc1': [64,3], 'fc2':[128,3], 'fc3':[256,5], 'fc4': [128, 2],
              'qc1': [64,3], 'qc2':[128,3], 'qc3':[256,5], 'qc4': [128, 2],
              'tfc1': [64,(3,3)], 'tfc2':[128,(3,3)], 'tfc3':[256,(5,5)], 'tfc4': [128, (2,2)],
              'dense1': 1000, 'dense2': 100, 'dense3': 200,'dense4': 300, 'dense5': 200,
              'out' : NUM_CLASSES
            }
iter = tf.data.Iterator.from_string_handle(handle, train_dataset.output_types, train_dataset.output_shapes)
X,FREQ,QUEF,SPECG,Y = iter.get_next()
X.set_shape([FLAGS.batch_size,768,14])
FREQ.set_shape([FLAGS.batch_size,384,14])
QUEF.set_shape([FLAGS.batch_size,384,14])
SPECG.set_shape([FLAGS.batch_size,65,18,14])
logit = net.run(X,FREQ,QUEF,SPECG,W)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=Y,logits=logit))
```

And the the file net.py:

```
def run(X,FREQ,QUEF,SPECG,W):
    time = tf.layers.batch_normalization(X,axis=-1,training=True,trainable=True)
    freq = tf.layers.batch_normalization(FREQ,axis=-1,training=True,trainable=True)
    quef = tf.layers.batch_normalization(QUEF,axis=-1,training=True,trainable=True)
    time_freq = tf.layers.batch_normalization(SPECG,axis=-1,training=True,trainable=True)


    regularizer = tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(0.1);
    #########################################################################################################
    #### TIME SUBNET
    with tf.device('/GPU:1'):
        tc1 = tf.layers.conv1d(inputs=time,filters=W['tc1'][0],kernel_size=W['tc1'][1],strides=1,padding='SAME',kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.random_normal,kernel_regularizer=regularizer,name='tc1')
        trelu1 = tf.nn.relu(features=tc1,name='trelu1')
        tpool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling1d(trelu1,pool_size=2,strides=1)

        tc2 = tf.layers.conv1d(inputs=tpool1,filters=W['tc2'][0],kernel_size=W['tc2'][1],strides=1,padding='SAME',kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.random_normal,kernel_regularizer=regularizer,name='tc2')
        tc3 = tf.layers.conv1d(inputs=tc2,filters=W['tc3'][0],kernel_size=W['tc3'][1],strides=1,padding='SAME',kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.random_normal,kernel_regularizer=regularizer,name='tc3')
        trelu2 = tf.nn.relu(tc3,name='trelu2')
        tpool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling1d(trelu2,pool_size=2,strides=1)

        tc4 = tf.layers.conv1d(inputs=tpool2,filters=W['tc4'][0],kernel_size=W['tc4'][1],strides=1,padding='SAME',kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.random_normal,kernel_regularizer=regularizer,name='tc4')
        tsubnet_out = tf.nn.relu6(tc4,'trelu61')
    #########################################################################################################
    #### CEPSTRUM SUBNET (QUEFRENCIAL)
        qc1 = tf.layers.conv1d(inputs=quef,filters=W['qc1'][0],kernel_size=W['qc1'][1],strides=1,padding='SAME',kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.random_normal,kernel_regularizer=regularizer,name='qc1')
        qrelu1 = tf.nn.relu(features=qc1,name='qrelu1')
        qpool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling1d(qrelu1,pool_size=2,strides=1)

        qc2 = tf.layers.conv1d(inputs=qpool1,filters=W['qc2'][0],kernel_size=W['qc2'][1],padding='SAME',strides=1,kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.random_normal,kernel_regularizer=regularizer,name='qc2')
        qc3 = tf.layers.conv1d(inputs=qc2,filters=W['qc3'][0],kernel_size=W['qc3'][1],padding='SAME',strides=1,kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.random_normal,kernel_regularizer=regularizer,name='qc3')
        qrelu2 = tf.nn.relu(qc3,name='qrelu2')
        qpool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling1d(qrelu2,pool_size=2,strides=1)

        qc4 = tf.layers.conv1d(inputs=qpool2,filters=W['qc4'][0],kernel_size=W['qc4'][1],padding='SAME',strides=1,kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.random_normal,kernel_regularizer=regularizer,name='qc4')
        qsubnet_out = tf.nn.relu6(qc4,'qrelu61')
    #########################################################################################################
    #FREQ SUBNET  
    with tf.device('/GPU:1'):
        fc1 = tf.layers.conv1d(inputs=freq,filters=W['fc1'][0],kernel_size=W['fc1'][1],padding='SAME',strides=1,kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.random_normal,kernel_regularizer=regularizer,name='fc1')
        frelu1 = tf.nn.relu(features=fc1,name='trelu1')
        fpool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling1d(frelu1,pool_size=2,strides=1)

        fc2 = tf.layers.conv1d(inputs=fpool1,filters=W['fc2'][0],kernel_size=W['fc2'][1],padding='SAME',strides=1,kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.random_normal,kernel_regularizer=regularizer,name='fc2')
        fc3 = tf.layers.conv1d(inputs=fc2,filters=W['fc3'][0],kernel_size=W['fc3'][1],padding='SAME',strides=1,kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.random_normal,kernel_regularizer=regularizer,name='fc3')
        frelu2 = tf.nn.relu(fc3,name='frelu2')
        fpool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling1d(frelu2,pool_size=2,strides=1)

        fc4 = tf.layers.conv1d(inputs=fpool2,filters=W['fc4'][0],kernel_size=W['fc4'][1],padding='SAME',strides=1,kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.random_normal,kernel_regularizer=regularizer,name='fc4')
        fsubnet_out = tf.nn.relu6(fc4,'frelu61')


    ########################################################################################################
    ## TIME/FREQ SUBNET
    with tf.device('/GPU:0'):
        tfc1 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=time_freq,filters=W['tfc1'][0],kernel_size=W['tfc1'][1],padding='SAME', strides=1,kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.random_normal,kernel_regularizer=regularizer,name='tfc1')
        tfrelu1 = tf.nn.relu(tfc1)
        tfpool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(tfrelu1,pool_size=[2, 2],strides=[1, 1])

        tfc2 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=tfpool1,filters=W['tfc2'][0],kernel_size=W['tfc2'][1],padding='SAME', strides=1,kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.random_normal,kernel_regularizer=regularizer,name='tfc2')
        tfc3 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=tfc2,filters=W['tfc3'][0],kernel_size=W['tfc3'][1],padding='SAME', strides=1,kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.random_normal,kernel_regularizer=regularizer,name='tfc3')
        tfrelu2 = tf.nn.relu(tfc3)
        tfpool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(tfrelu2,pool_size=[2, 2], strides=[1, 1])

        tfc4 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=tfpool2,filters=W['tfc4'][0],kernel_size=W['tfc4'][1],padding='SAME', strides=1,kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.random_normal,kernel_regularizer=regularizer,name='tfc4')
        tfsubnet_out = tf.nn.relu6(tfc4,'tfrelu61')
        ########################################################################################################
       ##Flatten subnet outputs
        tsubnet_out = tf.layers.flatten(tsubnet_out)
        fsubnet_out = tf.layers.flatten(fsubnet_out)
        tfsubnet_out = tf.layers.flatten(tfsubnet_out)
        qsubnet_out = tf.layers.flatten(qsubnet_out)

        #Final subnet computation
        input_final = tf.concat((tsubnet_out,fsubnet_out,qsubnet_out,tfsubnet_out),1)
        dense1 = tf.layers.dense(input_final,W['dense1'],tf.nn.relu, kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.random_normal,name='dense1')
        dense2 = tf.layers.dense(dense1,W['dense2'],tf.nn.relu, kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.random_normal,name='dense2')
        dense3 = tf.layers.dense(dense2,W['dense3'],tf.nn.relu, kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.random_normal,name='dense3')
        dense4 = tf.layers.dense(dense3,W['dense4'],tf.nn.relu, kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.random_normal,name='dense4')
        dense5 = tf.layers.dense(dense4,W['dense5'],tf.nn.relu, kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.random_normal,name='dense5')
        out = tf.layers.dense(dense5,W['out'],tf.nn.relu, name='out')
    return out
```

Comment: Without code and error messages, nobody can give you an answer, the problem is not conceptual, there is some error in your code or data.

Comment: Added the code if any part else is needed please, ask and I will provide

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally after some days, I've been able to track the problem. Which was not related to the code, I submitted, in the end. But it was related to the creation of the Tensorflow Dataset. Since in the batchin, if the length of the Dataset was not divisible by the batch size. The flag drop_remainder to True.

I will not delete the question since I believe is a problem that more people may have in the future and the source is not easily identificable.